# Invalid identifier when using left outer join in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote a query with Left outer join in oracle.But I execute the query I get `ORA-00904: "b"."GROSS_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT": invalid identifier` error.TableB contains net_discount_number and gross_discount_amount columns.

```
     select   
     a.GSMNO  GSMNO,
     a.NET_AMOUNT  net,
     a.GROSS_AMOUNT  gross,
     sum(b.net_discount_amount) net_discount, sum(b.gross_discount_amount) gross_discount,
     a.code code, a.seq_no
     from  tableA   a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select  id, code, seq_no, sum(gross_amount) gross_amount, sum(net_discount_amount), sum(gross_discount_amount) from tableB 
    group by id, code, seq_no)  
    b ON a.id = b.id and NVL(a.code,b.code) = NVL(b.code,-99) and  
    NVL(a._seq_no,-99)  = NVL(b.seq_no,-99)
    and a.gross_amount = b.gross_amount
 where  a.tvNo like  '123% and gsmno ='1111111111' 
 group by   
    a.GSMNO,
    a.NET_AMOUNT,
    a.GROSS_AMOUNT,
    a.code, a.seq_no
```

Comment: Please explain the purpose of your query. Sample data and desired results, provided as tabular text, would also be helpful.

Comment: Should `NVL(a._seq_no,-99)` be `NVL(a.seq_no,-99)`? Should `like '123% and gsmno ='1111111111'` be `like '123%' and gsmno ='1111111111'`?

Comment: Actually.It is working but TableB is very slow so I added index tableB with 5 columns but It is still running slowly.I think group by causes this problem

Comment: You need to show real execution plan with statistics to get suggestions about speeding up your qurry

Comment: I donot know execution plan.I execute tableB with select * from it executes fast but if I add group by It executes slowly.TableB contains 50 million records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified aliases for aggregate sums, it should be like this:

```sql
select   
     a.GSMNO  GSMNO,
     a.NET_AMOUNT  net,
     a.GROSS_AMOUNT  gross,
     sum(b.net_discount_amount) net_discount, sum(b.gross_discount_amount) gross_discount,
     a.code code, a.seq_no
     from  tableA   a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select  id, code, seq_no, 
sum(gross_amount) gross_amount,
 sum(net_discount_amount) net_discount_amount,
 sum(gross_discount_amount) gross_discount_amount
from tableB 
    group by id, code, seq_no)  
    b ON a.id = b.id and NVL(a.code,b.code) = NVL(b.code,-99) and  
    NVL(a._seq_no,-99)  = NVL(b.seq_no,-99)
    and a.gross_amount = b.gross_amount
 where  a.tvNo like  '123% and gsmno ='1111111111' 
 group by   
    a.GSMNO,
    a.NET_AMOUNT,
    a.GROSS_AMOUNT,
    a.code, a.seq_no
```

Comment: It is working but slowly.I think tableB is running slowly.How can I increase execution speed.?

Comment: Should I create an index with columns(id,code,seq_no,gross_amount,net_discount_amount,gross_discount_amount)?